# Cannot run function defined in UIViewController passed to SwiftUI view with UIHostingController?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass a function to a SwiftUI view (from UIKit) using UIHostingController that is being called with a .openUrl closure but I don't think I am either passing or defining it correctly via UIKit view because if I use all SwiftUI the function will run.

I get the below error when attempting to run the function when it is passed to a UIHostingController containing a SwiftUI view from a UIKit UIViewController

**[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60....**

I have the URL "refresh" typed correctly and it matches the one defined in **URL Types** in my Target (see image).

I have also tried defining func action() outside of loadInitialScreen() and passed to UIHostingController -> MessageView as self.action() but this did not work either.

Why am I getting this error, Am I passing or defining the action() function in RootViewController incorrectly to UIHostingController or what???

[image]

**UIKit View Controller**

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadInitialScreen()
    }
    
    func loadInitialScreen() {
        let messageViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:
               MessageView(messageTitle: "Title", action: { action() })
        )
     
        func action() {
            print("ACTION PRESSED")
        }
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(messageViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

**SwiftUI View**

```
struct MessageView: View {

    let messageTitle: String
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {action()}, label: {
          HStack {
             Text("[\(messageTitle)](refresh://action)")
             + Text(" Text")
          }.onOpenURL { _ in
              action()
          }
       })
    }

}
```

Comment: Try putting the action outside the function

Comment: I get the same error....